# Using re.finditer won't return all matches

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tkinter, text-coloring

I've been making a simple colorizer in python. It uses re.finditer to find the index of **all** words between quotation marks and color those words in a tkinter Text box. For some reason, when the box opens, not all of the words  have been found. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

def htmlbasiccolorer(self):
        def find2(self, color, warning):
                    string = (str(self.get("1.0",tk.END)))
                    lines=string.split("\n")
                    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
                                y=(i+1)
                                for e in re.finditer(r'"(.*?)"', line):
                                    startindex= e.start()
                                    endindex= e.end()
                                    startindex=(str(y)+'.'+(str(startindex)))
                                    endindex=(str(y)+'.'+(str(endindex)))
                                    startindex=float(startindex)
                                    endindex=float(endindex)
                                    startindex=(round(float(startindex), 2))
                                    endindex=(round(float(endindex), 2))
                                    self.tag_configure(warning, background="white", foreground=color)
                                    self.tag_add(warning, startindex, endindex)
        find2(self, "purple", "id-6")
s=tk.Tk()
s.geometry('1000x600')
t=tk.Text(s)
t.insert(tk.END, """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xml:lang="en-US"
  lang="en-US"
  dir="ltr"
  xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  class=" user-logged-out">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# game: http://ogp.me/ns/game#">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOODP" />
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOYDIR" />
        <meta name="verify-v1" content="TgxixMKtxcQ+9NUdD7grKbzw3tAl3iJWlTPSPKt9t0I=" />
    <meta name="p:domain_verify" content="314c7ba9469cc171a12a46b43e0e2aed" />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="n7BdKb0xn1E9tRJXvmMxE3Ynr-QajBOi1yA1srT4Nrc" />
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=329218549">

              <meta name="description" content="Play chess on Chess.com - the #1 chess community with +20 million members around the world. Play online with friends, challenge the computer, join a club, solve puzzles, analyze your games, and learn from hundreds of video lessons. You can also watch top players and compete for prizes." />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="//betacssjs.chesscomfiles.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="//images.chesscomfiles.com">

    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//betacssjs.chesscomfiles.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//images.chesscomfiles.com">

    <link
    as="font"
    crossorigin="crossorigin"
    href="/bundles/web/fonts/chessglyph-regular.d4a95b80.woff2"
    rel="preload"
    type="font/woff2">

    <link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/+chess"/>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://betacssjs.chesscomfiles.com
    <div id="challenge-popover"></div>
    <div id="message-popover"></div>
    <div id="modal-video"></div>
    <div id="trophy-popover"></div>
    <div id="user-popover"></div>
    </body>
</html>

""")
t.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
htmlbasiccolorer(t)
s.mainloop()
```

Below is an example of what it looks like. The purple text has been found and the black text hasn't. Some of the text between two quotation marks is still black.
[image]
I'm using python 3.6 on Windows 10.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What words are not found? Last `link` tag is broken - missing `"/>`, hence it's not being recognised. I'm also not sure why you iterate over the lines themselves (finditer works on multiline) and why you use so many parentheses.

Comment: The broken tags don't matter because it only searches for quotation marks. The last tag doesn't have a " at ther end so it won't be recognised. I did that as a test. I edited the question to show the output (eg. "NOYDIR" word is missed). I iterate over the lines because otherwise the startindex for the tkinter tag will be incorrect (format: [line, chars in from beginning of line]). I've deleted the extra parentheses.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Regex looks correct, and I have run the regex itself (not your code) - so it may be a problem with your colouring, not finditer. Print/log e.group(0) or e.group(1) (first is a full match, second is only the parentheses part) and see for yourself.

Comment: I tried debugging and just printing the matches, but it still missed some words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a float for the text widget indexes. The indexes are not floats, they are strings of the form *line*.*column*. You are then making the odd choice of rounding the index up or down.

Let's take a look at "NOYDIR" as an example, since that's one you claim it isn't finding. With just a single print statement you'll see that it's finding NOYDIR, but the indexes it is computing are 14.32 as the start, and 14.4 as the end. Because the end index is before the start index (character 4 is before character 32), tkinter won't highlight that word.

Why is the second index 14.4? It is because `e.start()` returns 40. You convert that to a float by appending a "." and the value to the row, yielding "1.40". You then convert it to a float, which converts "1.40" to "1.4". This is exactly why you should not treat text widget indexes as floats. The index is a *string* in the form of *line*.*column*. When you convert it to a float, the value "14.40" is indentical to "14.4", but to the text widget "14.40" and "14.4" are very different things.

Comment: Thank you! I deleted lines 15-18 and  now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found in *tkinter* documentation that index should be
passed as a **string**, containing row and column number,
separated with a dot.

So it looks weird to me that you change the indices to **float** and then round them.

I think, these instructions should be dropped.